# NCurses, Python y POO

Tags: python

estoy investigando como funciona la librería curses. Tengo una clase madre que me crea ventanas y paneles curses y una clase hija que quiero que me cree como una especie de widgets, mi problema es que no puedo agregar texto en estos widgets desde la clase hija, solo puedo agregar texto al crear la ventana desde la clase madre cuando hago su instancia. Cualquier ayuda se agradece. A continuación dejo código y errores.

Clase madre que llama a curses y a la función curses.newwin()

```
import curses, curses.panel

class BasicWindow:

    Height = 0
    Width = 0
    Pos_Y = 0
    Pos_X = 0
    Color = None
    Screen = None
    Title = ""
    TitlePosition = 0 
    win = None
    panel = None

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create_window(self):

        win = curses.newwin(
                self.Height,
                self.Width,
                self.Pos_Y,
                self.Pos_X
            )
        win.erase()
        win.attron(self.Color)
        win.bkgd(self.Color)
        win.box()

        tittle_pos = (self.Width // 2) - (len(self.Title) // 2)

        if not self.Title == "":

            if self.TitlePosition == 0:
                win.addch(0, tittle_pos - 1, curses.ACS_RTEE)
                win.attron(curses.A_REVERSE)
                win.addstr(0, tittle_pos , self.Title)
                win.attroff(curses.A_REVERSE)
                win.addch(0, tittle_pos + len(self.Title), curses.ACS_LTEE)
            elif self.TitlePosition == 1:
                win.addch(0, 1, curses.ACS_RTEE)
                win.attron(curses.A_REVERSE)
                win.addstr(0, 2 , self.Title)
                win.attroff(curses.A_REVERSE)
                win.addch(0, 2 + len(self.Title), curses.ACS_LTEE)
            else:
                win.addch(0, (self.Width - len(self.Title)) - 3, curses.ACS_RTEE)
                win.attron(curses.A_REVERSE)
                win.addstr(0, (self.Width - len(self.Title) - 2) , self.Title)
                win.attroff(curses.A_REVERSE)
                win.addch(0, self.Width - 2, curses.ACS_LTEE)


        panel = curses.panel.new_panel(win)
        self.win = win
        return win, panel

    def show(self):
        self.win, self.panel = self.create_window()
        self.win.refresh()
        curses.panel.update_panels()

    def hide(self):
        self.panel.hide()
        curses.panel.update_panels()

    def printstr(self, y, x, strg):
        self.win.addstr(y, x, strg)
```

Ahora la clase hija que intenta crear "Widget"

```
from ventanas.BasicWindow import *
import curses, curses.panel

class InfoWidget(BasicWindow): #Hereda de BasicWindow

    Label = ""
    Text = ""

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __create_widget(self):
        self.win, self.panel = self.create_window()
        self.win.addstr(2, 2, self.Label)


    def ShowWitget(self):
        self.__create_widget()
```

Y la instancia, de la clase en cualquier parte de main:

```
    wd_1 = InfoWidget()
    wd_1.Screen = win_inicio
    wd_1.Title = " Racaudación "
    wd_1.TitlePosition = 0
    wd_1.Label = "Total: "
    wd_1.Pos_X = 2
    wd_1.Pos_Y = 2
    wd_1.Height = 5
    wd_1.Width = 30
    wd_1.Color = curses.color_pair(3)
    wd_1.ShowWitget()
    wd_1.show()
```

Veo que tampoco me deja usar la función `win.addstr(y, x ,string)` con ninguna ventana excepto la principal `curses.stdscr()`.

el error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 135, in <module>
    curses.wrapper(Miapp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/curses/__init__.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "main.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.handle_keybinding()
  File "main.py", line 121, in handle_keybinding
    self.Inicio()
  File "main.py", line 109, in Inicio
    wd_Arqueos.Screen.addstr(2, 2, "lñkfdsñlfk")
AttributeError: 'BasicWindow' object has no attribute 'addstr'
```

Muchas gracias de antemano, solo es con medios educativos aprender a usar esta libreria, en realidad estoy aprendiendo python y me pareció interesante poder crear un entorno texto un poco mas amigable.

Answer (score 0):

Tu clase `BasicWindow` no expone la funcion `addstr` ni tampoco la hereda de ningún otro sitio, por lo que `InfoWidget` tampoco. Que `BasicWindow` sí funcione es porque instancias una clase de curses en `win = curses.newwin(..)` pero InfoWidget no la vé ni la hereda.

Comment: Si, cierto, muchas gracias. Investigo y lo expongo aqui. Otra vez gracias.

Comment: Porque `curses` es el nombre del módulo. No controlo muy bien POO o ncurses, pero podrías probar a crear otra clase como BasicWindow con otro tamaño y llamarla después para ver si "monta" la ventana encima